# Knockout.js - foreach binding - test if last element

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am using the following template:

```
<div class="datatypeOptions" data-bind="if: $data.datatypeTemplate().allowOptions">
    <h3>Allowed responses</h3>

    <p data-bind="if: $data.datatypeTemplate().datatypeOptions().length == 0">There are no responses for this question, yet. <a href="#" data-bind="click: function(d, e){$root.addDatatypeOption($data.datatypeTemplate());}">Add one</a>
    <ul data-bind="foreach: $data.datatypeTemplate().datatypeOptions()">
        <li>
            <a href="#" data-bind="text: name, click: $root.selectedDatatypeOption, visible: $data !== $root.selectedDatatypeOption()"></a>
            <input data-bind="value: name, visibleAndSelect: $data === $root.selectedDatatypeOption(), event: { blur: $root.clearDatatypeOption }, executeOnEnter: { callback: function(){ $root.addDatatypeOption($parent.datatypeTemplate()); } }" />
            //I want to show this a tag only if $data is the last element in the array.
Problem here ===>  <a href="#" data-bind="if: $data == $parent.datatypeTemplate().datatypeOptions()[ $parent.datatypeTemplate().datatypeOptions().length - 1 ], click: function(d, e){$root.addDatatypeOption($data.datatypeTemplate());}"><img src='/static/img/icons/custom-task-wizard/black/plus_12x12.png' title='Add option'></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I get this error in the console:

```
Uncaught Error: Unable to parse bindings.
Message: TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'datatypeTemplate';
Bindings value: if: $data == $parent.datatypeTemplate().datatypeOptions()[ $parent.datatypeTemplate().datatypeOptions().length - 1 ], click: function(d, e){$root.addDatatypeOption($data.datatypeTemplate());}
```

Is my only option to add a function to my viewmodel that returns true/false if the passed element is last in the array?

Comment: http://memegenerator.net/instance/14211604

Comment: You might want to try to reproduce this in jsFiddle.  The one thing that I did notice is that you are missing a closing your `p` tag, which can cause issues in binding/context.  You can keep your view cleaner by putting a computed observable or a function on your view model to help determine the last item.

Answer (score 89):

I've simplified the problem, but this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/poztin/jRkfL/2/) demonstrates a possible solution.

**"if" binding:**

```html
<div data-bind="if: ($index() === ($parent.data().length - 1))">I'm the last element</div>
```

**Containerless "if" binding:**

```html
<!-- ko if: ($index() === ($parent.data().length - 1)) -->
<div>I'm the last element again</div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

You can use `$index` within a `foreach` binding to get the index of the currently bound item. Use that to compare against the original collection of the parent.

See [HERE](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html) for more information regarding binding contexts.

Comment: Unfortunately, if you use the `as` option, `$data` is not also bound .. just a "gotcha".

Comment: This did not work for me, I think maybe b/c I'm on knockout v 2.2.1.  However the following did work (replace MyWingDings with the name of your array object, of course).  data-bind="visible: $index() < $parent.MyWingDings.length - 1"

Comment: @user2246674 see **[my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43210076/4390133)** in case you are using `as` option

Answer (score 10):

I noticed there are a number of requests for enhancements to KO to support the `$length`, `$last`, or `$array` reserved properties in the `foreach` binding although, for a variety of reasons (often performance), they have not made it into the codebase.

If anyone is interested in exposing these elements for a specific case using a custom binding, here is a simple example of exposing the `$length` variable in order to print a "pretty" list. 
 You simply use `forEachWithLength` anywhere you would normally use `foreach`.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.forEachWithLength = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, context)
    {         
        return ko.bindingHandlers.foreach.init(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, context);
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, context) 
    {         
        var array = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        var extendedContext = context.extend({"$length" : array.length });
        ko.bindingHandlers.foreach.update(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, extendedContext);   
    }
};
```

Example usage:

```
<div data-bind="forEachWithLength: myArray">
    <span data-bind="text: $data"></span>
    <!-- ko if: ($index() < $length-2) -->, <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- ko if: ($index() === $length-2) --> and <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

**Input :** `["One", "Two", "Three", "Four"]`

**Output :** `One, Two, Three and Four`

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ln2ua/1/)

[Further reading](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings-controlling-descendant-bindings.html)

Comment: This doesn't really work if you have an observableArray that is dynamically modified. Adding an element to the observable array does not re-evaluate the templates that have already been rendered. Example forked from your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ek4vujy7/

Answer (score 4):

If you are **NOT** using `as` option in the `foreach` binding, then go to the **[most-upvoted answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13368297/4390133)**. 
If you are **DO** using `as` operator in the `foreach` binding. then that answer will **NOT** work.

Here is the solution in that case

```
<div data-bind="foreach:{data: Items, as :'item'}">
    <div data-bind="if: ($index() === ($parent.Items().length - 1))">I'm the last element</div>
</div>
```

The secret with replacing the `$parent.data()` with the name of the observable array you are using. 
 *In my case it was named `Items`*, so I replaced the `$parent.data()` with `$parent.Items()`

**Note** this solution is working in all cases, (*in case you are using `as` option in foreach or not*)

Comment: How to get the last index in the nested loop?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1. Use `$root` instead of `$parent`
2. Prepare the last item in advance and pass this item to your template as additional parameter.
3. Encapsulate the last element to observable.