# Find the last iteration of foreach data-bind in knockout js

Tags: html, css, knockout.js, foreach

**Is there a way to find last iteration using foreach data-bind in knockout js?**

My problem is, I am iterating over a list of items and want to print all items separated by
a line.

I don't want to draw a line(hr) for the last item of that array.

Comment: Sounds like this is more of a CSS / layout problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Knockout.js - foreach binding - test if last element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9185821/knockout-js-foreach-binding-test-if-last-element)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check if you are displaying the first element.

```
<div data-bind="foreach: items">
   <hr data-bind="visible : $index()!=0" /> 
   <span data-bind="text: $data"></span>
</div>
```

[**See fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Zyj36/)

Or as RP Niemeyer said, you can omit the last hr :

```
<div data-bind="foreach: items">
   <span data-bind="text: $data"></span>
   <hr data-bind="visible : $index() != ($parent.length-1)" /> 
   // notice the hr is after the item.
</div>
```

Comment: I wanted to check last element. But your code checks for first element. But it works. Can you eloborate?

Comment: To insert hr only between two items. You can either remove the last extra hr or the first.

Answer (score 8):

Inside of a foreach, you can bind against a special context variable (observable) called `$index`.  So, you could bind something like `visible: $index() < $parent.items().length - 1`.

Sample:
http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/M55qh/

Comment: CSS would be a fine way to go too, if that is all you need

Answer (score 3):

With CSS maybe you can use `last-child`, try:

```
hr:last-child {
  display:none;
}
```

And if you can be more specific like adding the `id` of parent container.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use `visible: $index() < list().length` or something similar?

http://jsfiddle.net/x2aa7/