# Conditionally styling the last element in a knockout.js foreach loop

Tags: javascript, css, knockout.js

I have a small chunk of code that I believe should work, line broken for clarity here:

```
<!-- ko foreach: customer.address -->
    <span data-bind="style: { display: $index() === ($parent.data().length -1) 
                        ? 'inline-block' : 'block' }, text: $data.text"></span>
<!-- /ko -->
```

My aim here is to loop around printing out span elements, most of which are set to `display: block` and the last is set to `display: inline-block`.  It does not appear to matter how I bracket up the conditional, it doesn't work and returns this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Unable to process binding "foreach: function (){return customer.address }"
Message: Unable to process binding "style: function (){return { display:$index() ===($parent.data().length -1) ?'inline-block':'block'} }"
Messag...<omitted>...a'
```

Modifying the conditional to something that otherwise evaluates to true is fine, e.g. `display: (1 === 1) ? 'inline-block' : 'block'.  Of note also is that the conditional to check for the last element is also OK, under other circumstances, and came from this SO question:

[Knockout.js foreach binding test if last element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9185821/knockout-js-foreach-binding-test-if-last-element)

How should I go about conditionally applying a style or other attribute to the last element in a foreach loop?  I am trying to avoid having two `<!-- ko if: -->` and two different `<span>` lines, but if that's what's needed then let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `data()` property your on `$parent`.

In the linked sample it is working because the array is called `data` on the parent.

You have your array in the `customer.address` property so you need to use that:

```
<!-- ko foreach: customer.address -->
    <span data-bind="style: { display: $index() === ($parent.customer.address.length -1) 
                        ? 'inline-block' : 'block' }, text: $data.text"></span>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/puZwT/1/).

Note: you need to write `address()` if your `address` is an observable array so `$parent.customer.address().length`

If you don't want to repeat the array name you can use the `with` binding to wrap your `foreach`:

```
<!-- ko with: customer.address -->
    <!-- ko foreach: $data -->
        <span data-bind="style: { display: $index() === ($parent.length -1)  
               ? 'inline-block' : 'block' }, text: $data"></span>
    <!-- /ko -->
<!-- /ko -->
```

in this case the `$parent` will directly point to your array so no need to repeat its "path".

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2J2U8/).

However if only want to style the last element and there is no additional logic related to it you can achieve this with using pure CSS3 with the `last-child` selector.

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MC46h/).

Comment: And this is why people should avoid using variable names that are potentially reserved (e.g. $data).  Thank you, I clearly misread the intent behind the answer I referenced.

Comment: There is even a pure CSS3 solution for this, I've updated my answer with a sample.

Comment: last-child was my first step, I just couldn't get last-child to work when applied to span elements inside a `<dd>` tag though I am using fine elsewhere, for example `<li>`s inside a `<ul>`.  Hmm I'll have to revisit that, clearly it should have worked as I just fiddled your fiddle to check.